# Singularity and/or non-significant digits in BVP with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I have the following code, in which I try to solve a system of three coupled differential equation numerically:

The code:

```
    (*Parameters*)

    (*precision:20,50,\[Infinity]*)

    pr := \[Infinity]
    prr := pr - 5

    cut := 1/1000000000
    \[Epsilon] := SetPrecision[1/10, pr]
    L := SetPrecision[1, pr]
    d := SetPrecision[1/100, pr]
    \[Phi] := SetPrecision[\[Pi]/8, pr]
    \[Chi]m := SetPrecision[0, pr]
    \[Chi]p := SetPrecision[0, pr]
    \[Alpha]p := SetPrecision[1, pr]
    N5 := SetPrecision[2, pr]
    N3 := SetPrecision[20, pr]
    \[CapitalDelta]N3 := SetPrecision[2, pr]
    gYM := SetPrecision[10, pr]
    \[Delta] = 
      SetPrecision[
       1/2 Log[1/(
          gYM^2 N5^2 (2 N3 - \[CapitalDelta]N3)) (2 gYM^2 N3 N5^2 + 
            4 \[Pi]^2 \[CapitalDelta]N3^2 + 
            Sqrt[(2 gYM^2 N3 N5^2 + 4 \[Pi]^2 \[CapitalDelta]N3^2)^2 - 
              gYM^4 N5^4 (4 N3^2 - \[CapitalDelta]N3^2)])], pr];
    \[Alpha] = 
      SetPrecision[-(N5/4) Cosh[\[Delta]] + 
        Sqrt[(\[Pi]^2 N3)/gYM^2 + N5^2/16 Cosh[\[Delta]]^2], pr];
    \[Alpha]h = SetPrecision[(gYM^2 \[Alpha])/(4 \[Pi]), pr];

    (*harmonic functions and definitions*)

    h1 = \[Alpha]p (-I \[Alpha] Sinh[v] - 
          N5/4 Log[
            Tanh[(I \[Pi])/4 - (v - \[Delta])/
              2]]) + \[Alpha]p (I \[Alpha] Sinh[vb] - 
          N5/4 Log[Tanh[-((I \[Pi])/4) - (vb - \[Delta])/2]]);
    h2 = \[Alpha]p \[Alpha]h (Cosh[v] + Cosh[vb]);
    w = D[D[h1 h2, vb], v];
    F1 = 2 h1 h2 D[h1, v] D[h1, vb] - h1^2 w;
    F2 = 2 h1 h2 D[h2, v] D[h2, vb] - h2^2 w;
    f42s = N[2 ((F1 F2)/w^2)^(1/4), prr];
    \[Rho]2s = N[2 h2^2 ((F1 w^2)/F2^3)^(1/4), prr];
    subv = {v -> x[x2] + I y[x2], vb -> x[x2] - I y[x2]};

    (*Coeff functions inside the eoms*)

    (*THESE FUNCTIONS ARE INSIDE THE DIFFERENTIAL EQUATIONS BELOW*)

    (*these functions will be evaluated at the initial values given \
    below, BUT they give undefined values or non-significant digits \
    depending on the precision*)

    Logfx = SetPrecision[D[Log[f42s /. subv], x[x2]], prr];
    Logfy = SetPrecision[D[Log[f42s /. subv], y[x2]], prr];
    Log\[Rho]x = SetPrecision[D[Log[\[Rho]2s /. subv], x[x2]], prr];
    Log\[Rho]y = SetPrecision[D[Log[\[Rho]2s /. subv], y[x2]], prr];
    f\[Rho]x = 
      SetPrecision[D[f42s /. subv, x[x2]]/(\[Rho]2s /. subv), prr];
    f\[Rho]y = 
      SetPrecision[D[f42s /. subv, y[x2]]/(\[Rho]2s /. subv), prr];

    (*Lagrangian and equations of motion*)

    (*f42 is Subscript[f, 4](x,y)^2 and \[Rho]2 is \[Rho](x,y)^2*)
    (*Subscript[f, 4](x,y) and \[Rho](x,y) are given*)

    (*SUBSTITUTIONS*)

    subeq = { f42[x[x2], y[x2]] -> f42, 
    \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(f42\), 
    TagBox[
    RowBox[{"(", 
    RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
    Derivative],
    MultilineFunction->None]\)[x[x2], y[x2]] -> f42y, 
    \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(f42\), 
    TagBox[
    RowBox[{"(", 
    RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
    Derivative],
    MultilineFunction->None]\)[x[x2], y[x2]] -> 
        f42x, \[Rho]2[x[x2], y[x2]] -> \[Rho]2, 
    \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Rho]2\), 
    TagBox[
    RowBox[{"(", 
    RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
    Derivative],
    MultilineFunction->None]\)[x[x2], y[x2]] -> \[Rho]2x, 
    \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Rho]2\), 
    TagBox[
    RowBox[{"(", 
    RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
    Derivative],
    MultilineFunction->None]\)[x[x2], y[x2]] -> \[Rho]2y};

    (*I dont know if the last line will be clear as code, so I added a \
    copy of it below*)

    (*subeq={ f42[x[x2],y[x2]]\[Rule]f42,D[ \
    f42[x[x2],y[x2]],y[x2]]\[Rule]f42y,D[ \
    f42[x[x2],y[x2]],x[x2]]\[Rule]f42x,\[Rho]2[x[x2],y[x2]]\[Rule]\      [Rho]2,\
    D[\[Rho]2[x[x2],y[x2]],x[x2]]\[Rule]\[Rho]2x,D[\[Rho]2[x[x2],y[x2]],y[\
    x2]]\[Rule]\[Rho]2y};*)

    subu = {f42x -> A f42, f42y -> B f42};

    subxy = {f42x -> F \[Rho]2, 
       f42y -> G \[Rho]2, \[Rho]2x -> H \[Rho]2, \[Rho]2y -> J \[Rho]2};

    subwarp2 = {A -> Logfx, B -> Logfy, H -> Log\[Rho]x, J -> Log\[Rho]y, 
       F -> f\[Rho]x, G -> f\[Rho]y};

    (*Lagrangian*)

    Lag = f42[x[x2], y[x2]] (u'[x2]^2/u[x2]^2 + 2/u[x2]^2) + \[Rho]2[
         x[x2], y[x2]] (x'[x2]^2 + y'[x2]^2);

    (*SET OF EQUATIONS OF MOTION where A,B,F,G,H and J are defined above*)

    (*eom for u(x2)*)

    equ =  (u[x2]^2)/(2 f42) (D[Lag, u[x2]] - D[D[Lag, u'[x2]], x2]) /. 
         subeq /. subu // Expand;

    (*eom for x(x2)*)

    eqx =  1/(2 \[Rho]2) (D[Lag, x[x2]] - D[D[Lag, x'[x2]], x2]) /. 
         subeq /. subxy // Expand;

    (*eom for y(x2)*)

    eqy =  1/(2 \[Rho]2) (D[Lag, y[x2]] - D[D[Lag, y'[x2]], x2]) /. 
         subeq /. subxy // Expand;

    (*collecting the equations*)

    equu = (equ + u''[x2]) /. subwarp2;
    eqxx = (eqx + x''[x2]) /. subwarp2;
    eqyy = (eqy + y''[x2]) /. subwarp2;
    pdes = {u''[x2] == equu, x''[x2] == eqxx, y''[x2] == eqyy};


    (*Boundary conditions*)

    (*initial and final values of x2*)

    x20 = SetPrecision[-d Cos[\[Phi]], prr];
    x21 = SetPrecision[d Cos[\[Phi]], prr];

    (*initial values of u,x and y*)

    u0 = SetPrecision[\[Epsilon] Sqrt[
        1 + ((L - d Sin[\[Phi]])/\[Epsilon])^2], prr];
    x0 = SetPrecision[ArcSinh[(L - d Sin[\[Phi]])/\[Epsilon]], prr];
    y0 = SetPrecision[\[Pi]/2 - \[Chi]m, prr];

    (*Final values*)

    u1 = SetPrecision[\[Epsilon] Sqrt[
        1 + ((L + d Sin[\[Phi]])/\[Epsilon])^2], prr];
    x1 = SetPrecision[ArcSinh[(L + d Sin[\[Phi]])/\[Epsilon]], prr];
    y1 = SetPrecision[\[Pi]/2 - \[Chi]p, prr];
    (*required condition*)
    L - d Sin[\[Phi]] > 0

    (*boundary conditions*)

    bcs = SetPrecision[{x[x20] == x0, u[x20] == u0, y[x20] == y0, 
        x[x21] == x1, u[x21] == u1, y[x21] == y1}, prr];

    (*slight deformation of the initial conditions*)

    cor := SetPrecision[1/1000000, prr]
    bcs2 = SetPrecision[{x[x20] == x0 + cor, u[x20] == u0 + cor, 
        y[x20] == y0 + cor, x[x21] == x1 + cor, u[x21] == u1 + cor, 
        y[x21] == y1 + cor}, prr];

    (*Solving eoms*)

    (*NDSolve[Flatten[{pdes,bcs}],{u[x2],x[x2],y[x2]},{x2,x20,x21},Method\
    \[Rule]{"ExplicitRungeKutta","DifferenceOrder"\[Rule]2},\
    WorkingPrecision\[Rule]70][[1]];*)
    subin = SetPrecision[{u[x20] -> u0, x[x20] -> x0, y[x20] -> y0}, prr];
    subin2 = SetPrecision[{u[x20] -> u0 + cor, x[x20] -> x0 + cor, 
        y[x20] -> y0 + cor}, prr];

(*Evaluating the eoms at the initial value of x20*)

bcsin = {x[x20] == x0, u[x20] == u0, y[x20] == y0};
bcsin2 = {x[x20] == x0 + cor, u[x20] == u0 + cor, y[x20] == y0 + cor};
(*EVALUATION AT THE ORIGINAL INITIAL VALUES*)

NDSolve[Flatten[{pdes, bcs}], {u[x2], x[x2], y[x2]}, {x2, x20, x21}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> bcsin}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision][[1]];
NDSolve::ndsz: At x2 == -0.0092388, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

(*EVALUATION AT THE "DEFORMED INITIAL VALUES*)

NDSolve[Flatten[{pdes, bcs2}], {u[x2], x[x2], y[x2]}, {x2, x20, x21}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> bcsin2}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision][[1]];

NDSolve::ndsz: At x2 == -0.0092388, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
```

Now the problem. Initially, I set the variable to some numerical values, and there is a chain of definitions involving them, ok. Since some of them are trigonometric functions, square roots, etc; I set infinite precision (which displays numbers inside these functions, e.g `Sin[pi/2]` instead `Sin[3.14.../2]`), so coefficient functions are finally evaluated in those parameters and depend only on functions and numbers (with infinite precision, i.e non-functional expressions).

I know that Mathematica deal BVP with Shooting method. I also know that `NDSolve` needs numerical values inside the equations, that is why I set `WorkingPrecision` to `MachinePrecision`. The problema appear when I run the code and get

```
NDSolve::ndsz: "At x0 == (number), step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected."
```

So the problems looks to be at the beginning. I evaluated the coefficient functions inside the PDEs and saw that indeed `x=x0` gives something like

```
"Infinite expression 1/(0.*10^-37+0.*10^-37\I) encountered."
```

Maybe there are analytic zeroes inside the coefficient functions, I thought, so I applied `Chop` to set zero small numbers. When I evaluate the coefficient functions I get

```
no significant digits to display
```

And something like `0.x10^-20` or `0.x10^50`. These "numbers" spoil the evaluation and the method, I think... producing something like `1/0` in the middle steps.

Any suggestion? I hope you understand the problem.

Comment: Please display the actual code that produces the error.  Otherwise, it is nearly impossible for the reader to provide a useful answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey see below.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code in your "Answer", which surely will be deleted, because it is not, in fact, an answer.  When you do so, replace `**Parameters**` etc. by `(*Parameters*)`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Done

Comment: I have eliminated the error messages listed in the question but need more information to provide good guesses for the Shooting method.  What do you expect the solution to look like?  Is it real everywhere?  Is it approximately symmetric about the origin?  Are derivatives of the functions approximately zero at `x2 == 0`?  Etc.

Comment: Can the equations be rewritten to explicitly eliminate `I`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey The solutions for u, x and y must be real since they are coordinates with boundary values at x20 (initial) and x21 (final). About the derivatives, yes, I expect to have zero derivatives near x2==0, when solutions go back to the final point.  About symmetry, also yes, I expect symmetry around the origin x2==0, when u x and y go back to their final values.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I do expect that the equations were real, I think the code doesnt do that very well. So it would be useful to eliminate the imaginary part, yes.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message given in the question occurs because the ODEs are singular at `y[x2] == Pi/2`, which is the boundary condition given for `y` (see discussion at the end of this answer).  `SetPrecision` has no effect on this problem and only clutters the code.  With it and other unnecessary material deleted, the code becomes

```
ϵ = 1/10; L = 1; d = 1/100; ϕ = π/8; χm = 1/1000; χp = 1/1000; αp = 1; N5 = 2; 
    N3 = 20; ΔN3 = 2; gYM = 10;
δ = 1/2 Log[1/(gYM^2 N5^2 (2 N3 - ΔN3)) (2 gYM^2 N3 N5^2 + 4 π^2 ΔN3^2 + 
    Sqrt[(2 gYM^2 N3 N5^2 + 4 π^2 ΔN3^2)^2 - gYM^4 N5^4 (4 N3^2 - ΔN3^2)])];
α = -(N5/4) Cosh[δ] + Sqrt[(π^2 N3)/gYM^2 + N5^2/16 Cosh[δ]^2];
αh = (gYM^2 α)/(4 π);

h1 = αp (-I α Sinh[v] - N5/4 Log[Tanh[(I π)/4 - (v - δ)/2]]) + 
    αp (I α Sinh[vb] - N5/4 Log[Tanh[-((I π)/4) - (vb - δ)/2]]);
h2 = αp αh (Cosh[v] + Cosh[vb]);
w = D[D[h1 h2, vb], v];
F1 = 2 h1 h2 D[h1, v] D[h1, vb] - h1^2 w;
F2 = 2 h1 h2 D[h2, v] D[h2, vb] - h2^2 w;
f42s = 2 ((F1 F2)/w^2)^(1/4);
ρ2s = 2 h2^2 ((F1 w^2)/F2^3)^(1/4);
subv = {v -> x[x2] + I y[x2], vb -> x[x2] - I y[x2]};

Logfx = D[Log[f42s /. subv], x[x2]];
Logfy = D[Log[f42s /. subv], y[x2]];
Logρx = D[Log[ρ2s /. subv], x[x2]];
Logρy = D[Log[ρ2s /. subv], y[x2]];
fρx = D[f42s /. subv, x[x2]]/(ρ2s /. subv);
fρy = D[f42s /. subv, y[x2]]/(ρ2s /. subv);

subeq = {f42[x[x2], y[x2]] -> f42, D[f42[x[x2], y[x2]], y[x2]] -> f42y, 
         D[f42[x[x2], y[x2]], x[x2]] -> f42x, ρ2[x[x2], y[x2]] -> ρ2, 
         D[ρ2[x[x2], y[x2]], x[x2]] -> ρ2x, D[ρ2[x[x2], y[x2]], y[x2]] -> ρ2y};
subu = {f42x -> A f42, f42y -> B f42};
subxy = {f42x -> F ρ2, f42y -> G ρ2, ρ2x -> H ρ2, ρ2y -> J ρ2};
subwarp2 = {A -> Logfx, B -> Logfy, H -> Logρx, J -> Logρy, F -> fρx, G -> fρy};

Lag = f42[x[x2], y[x2]] (u'[x2]^2/u[x2]^2 + 2/u[x2]^2) + 
    ρ2[x[x2], y[x2]] (x'[x2]^2 + y'[x2]^2);
equ = (u[x2]^2)/(2 f42) (D[Lag, u[x2]] - D[D[Lag, u'[x2]], x2]) /. 
    subeq /. subu // Expand;
eqx =  1/(2 ρ2) (D[Lag, x[x2]] - D[D[Lag, x'[x2]], x2]) /. subeq /. subxy // Expand;
eqy =  1/(2 ρ2) (D[Lag, y[x2]] - D[D[Lag, y'[x2]], x2]) /. subeq /. subxy // Expand;
pdes = {equ == 0, eqx == 0, eqy == 0} /. subwarp2;

x20 = -d Cos[ϕ];
x21 = d Cos[ϕ];

u0 = ϵ Sqrt[1 + ((L - d Sin[ϕ])/ϵ)^2];
x0 = ArcSinh[(L - d Sin[ϕ])/ϵ];
y0 = π/2 - χm;

u1 = ϵ Sqrt[1 + ((L + d Sin[ϕ])/ϵ)^2];
x1 = ArcSinh[(L + d Sin[ϕ])/ϵ];
y1 = π/2 - χp;

bcs = {x[x20] == x0, u[x20] == u0, y[x20] == y0, 
       x[x21] == x1, u[x21] == u1, y[x21] == y1};

NDSolveValue[{pdes, bcs}, {u[x2], x[x2], y[x2]}, {x2, x20, x21}];
```

Unfortunately, `Method -> "Shooting"`, which is automatic here, invariably failed, even with initial guesses explicitly given, due to failure to converge or, more commonly, division by zero.  Note that `χm = 1/1000; χp = 1/1000` are used in the code above to avoid singularities at the boundaries that occurred in the question.  Some insight can be obtained from treating the calculation as an IVP instead of a BVP,

```
bcst = {u[x20] == u0, x[x20] == x0, y[x20] == y0, u'[x20] == 0, 
        x'[x20] == -10, y'[x20] == 10};
NDSolveValue[{pdes, bcst}, {u[x2], x[x2], y[x2]}, {x2, x20, x21}];
Plot[{Chop[%[[1]]], Chop[%[[2]]], Chop[%[[3]]]}, {x2, x20, x21}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], AxesLabel -> {"x2", "u, x, y"}]
```

[image]

Large changes to `x'[x20]` and `y'[x20]` have almost no impact on the curves shown.

Comments by the OP indicate that the desired solution is expected to be approximately symmetric about `x2 == 0`.  This suggests trying something like

```
bcst = {x[0] == x0 - .19, u[0] == u0, y[0] == Pi/2 - .08, x'[0] == 0, 
    y'[0] == 0, u'[0] == 0};
NDSolveValue[{pdes, bcst}, {u[x2], x[x2], y[x2]}, {x2, x20, x21}];
Plot[%, {x2, x20, x21}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], AxesLabel -> {"x2", "u, x, y"}]
(%% /. x2 -> x20) // Chop
```

[image]

```
(* {1.00111, 2.98889, 1.36707} *)
```

It is easy in this way to approximately match the boundary conditions for `x` and `u` given in the question.  However, the boundary conditions for `y` given in the question are far from being matched.  Based on my many attempts to obtain even approximately the desired `y` boundary conditions, I believe that they cannot be achieved.  (Remember that the ODEs are highly nonlinear.)

*Discussion of singularity at `y == Pi/2`*

The overall structure of the ODEs can be obtained as follows.

```
subwarphf = {A -> HoldForm@Logfx, B -> HoldForm@Logfy, H -> HoldForm@Logρx, 
    J -> HoldForm@Logρy, F -> HoldForm@fρx, G -> HoldForm@fρy}
```

[image]

However, the six quantities `Logfx` etc. have `LeafCount`s in the tens of thousands, and Mathematica cannot simplify them or expand them about `y[x2] == Pi/2` in a reasonable amount of time.  They can, however be plotted in minutes, showing that `Logρy` and `fρx` are singular there.  From the structure of the `eqx` and `eqy`, it is evident that they too must be singular unless `x'` and `y'` vanish identically there.

**Addendum: Solution Satisfying `u` and `x` Boundary Conditions**

In comments below, the OP requested a solution with `u` and `x` satisfying the boundary conditions given in the question, and `y` satisfying `0 < y[x2] < Pi/2` but otherwise unconstrained.  One such solution is given by

```
bcst = {u[x20] == u0, x[x20] == x0, y[x20] == 1.36707, 
        u'[x20] == 0.3504, x'[x20] == -18.9337, y'[x20] == 20.0155};
NDSolveValue[{pdes, bcst}, {u[x2], x[x2], y[x2]}, {x2, x20, x21}];
Plot[%, {x2, x20, x21}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], AxesLabel -> {"x2", "u, x, y"}]
Plot[First@%%, {x2, x20, x21}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], AxesLabel -> {"x2", "u"}]
{%%% /. x2 -> x20, %%% /. x2 -> x21} // Chop
```

[image]
[image]

```
(* {{1.00118, 2.99441, 1.36707}, {1.0088, 3.00202, 1.3649}} *)
```

Comparing `u[x21]` and `x[x21]` with

```
u1 // N
(* 1.0088 *)
x1 // N
(* 3.00202 *)
```

shows that the solution obtained here satisfies the `x21` boundary conditions to five significant figures.  I obtained the solution parameters starting from those for the second plot in the answer and then adjusting `u'[x20]` and `x'[x20]` to satisfy the two `x21` boundary conditions.  Using the "Shooting" `Method`, on the other hand, invariably failed.  It seems likely, nonetheless, that using `ParametricNDSolve` combined with `FindRoot`, appropriately tuned` would have yielded the answer I obtained by trial and error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, `y==Pi/2` as an initial and final value is not correct.  Even  taking `Chi_m=Chi_p=1/1000` as you considered looks to give strange plots, sorry for not being clear in that detail. I'm trying differente values for `y` at `x20` and `x21`, but this is matter of choosing a suitable set of numbers. Moreover, I dont understand the second set of conditions `bcst` which give the second plot, e.g  `u[0] == u0`.

Comment: `bcst` sets first derivatives of `y`, `x`, and `y`` to zero at `x2 == 0` and  integrates from there to `x20` and `x21`, thereby giving a solution which is symmetric about `x0 = 0`, as you suggested in a comment.  I chose values for the three functions themselves at `x2 == 0` to give values at the end points that were reasonably close to those in the question, except of course for `y`.  If you planned to try different values for `y` at the endpoints, what were your criteria for a successful choice?

Comment: The initial and endpoints of `x` `y` and `u` are `x20` and `x21`, which depend on `L`, `d` and `phi` (which must combine into a positive exression givenin the code); also `Chi_m`, `Chi_p` and `epsilon`. My mistake was to consider the initial and final values of `y` as equal. A successful choice of parameters should be `epsilon` small, e.g. `1/10` or `1/100`. About `y`, it must be greater than zero and less than `Pi/2`, and different at `x20` and `x21` (different `Chi`s). It is good to choose vanishing derivative of `x,y,u` at `x20==0`.

Comment: @resanrom  If I understand you correctly, you wish `u` and `x` to have the endpoint values specified in the question, Pi/2 > y > 0 to have unequal values at the endpoints, and `L - d Sin[ϕ] > 0`.  Is that correct?  If so, then it is not possible to have first derivatives of `u`, `x`, and `y` all equal to zero at `x2 == 0`, although they could be close to zero there.  Please clarify.  Also, are there any other constraints on the desired solution?

Comment: Yes, fixed points are specified before and unequal. Sorry again, I'm not being precise, I expect that `x` `y` and `u` behave as increasing functions, in general, until they reach `x2==0`, and then they decrease to their fixed value at `x2==x21`. In particular, I expect that `u` do that (like an "arc"), while for `x` and `y` I actually dont, but I could approximate that the also have vanishing first derivatives. No more constraints.

Comment: @r  I expect that `x` will behave as a decreasing function until it reaches `x2 == 0` and then increase to its value at `x2 == x21` instead, along the lines of my second plot, but I shall investigate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, what values of `Chi_m` you have taken? Also, what are the criteria to choose the first derivatives at `x20`?